# Some chat messages moved to another room still appear in original room

Tags: bug, chat, chat-search

I've found some messages that have been moved from chat room A to chat room B, yet still appear in searches for chat room A. Other messages that have been moved are excluded, as expected.

Reproduction:

- Search for the term "cv-pls" in Room 41570 (aka [SOCVR on Stack Overflow Chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41570/so-close-vote-reviewers))
- These messages get archived after some time, so expect to see many that are recent, and fewer back in time. Select an older page, and look for matching messages with "[cv-pls](/questions/tagged/cv-pls)" in them. Presently, [page 3](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/search?q=cv-pls&Room=41570&page=3&pagesize=50&sort=newest) shows some from October 3, as shown in the screenshot.

  [image: screenshot]
- Hover over the permalinks for find results, and note the page IDs in the URLs. As shown, some messages permalink to chat room B (90230, here).

  > These should not appear in the search results for Room A.
- Follow such a permalink, and check the history of the message. It shows that the message has been moved.

  [image: history]

Comment: FWIW, those misplaced messages do *not* show up when searching the room where they should be. For example, [this search](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/search?q=2017-10-03+04%3A02%3A05Z&room=90230) fails to find [this message](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/39424380#39424380).

Comment: This is also reported in this post on meta.SO: [Chat search turning up messages moved to another room](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/374950)